# angularjs: how to use a http url as templateUrl in angularjs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I want to use a http url as templateUrl in my angularjs directive like below:

```
angular.directive('mydir', function() {
       return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           ....
        },
        templateUrl: "example.com/def.html"
    }
});
```

But after changing it to the above url template is not getting visible on the page. Is there any workaround for this.

Comment: because it changing only field you put directive . pls post your html code

Comment: Two things; you don't actually include the HTTP scheme in the URL (i.e., it should be `templateUrl: "http://example.com/def.html"`). Secondly, this would require you to have permission to request that URL via ajax (using CORS). If you look at your network tab of your browser tools, you're likely getting an error.